# help for installing lidar on a drone

Tags: ros2, lidar, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

(note: I posted this question on gazebo forum, but it is seems to be a ros plugin, so I post here too)

I'm trying to install a lidar on a drone (x500, model provided by PX4 repo).
I found some examples, but all seems outdated.

For the plugin, an example give the name of `libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so`, another `libgazebo_ros_laser.so`. Some doc points to "https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs" to get the plugin, but the list of available branch is huge, and I already installed libgz-sim7-plugins on my machine (which contains libgz-sensors7-lidar.so that "does not export any plugins").

Well I'm totally lost !
Which plugin should I used ?

I'm using gazebo garden on ubuntu 22.04. Here is part of my sdf file

```
<sdf version="1.10">
  <model name="x500_lidar">
    <include><uri>model://x500</uri>[...]</include>

  <!--add lidar-->
  <link name="hokuyo_link">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    [...]
    <sensor type="gpu_ray" name="laser">
      <pose>0 0 0.3 0 0 1.57</pose>
      [...]
      <plugin name="hokuyo_node" filename="libgz-sensors7-lidar.so">
        <robotNamespace></robotNamespace>
        <topicName>/spur/laser/scan</topicName>
        <frameName>/hokuyo_sensor_link</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </link>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417971/help-for-installing-lidar-on-a-drone/) by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2023-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own question : I found solution in `ros_gz/ros_gz_sim_demos/launch/gpu_lidar_bridge.launch.py`

In there, I read that plugin `gz-sim-sensors-system` was the one to use, I have had this clue somewhere, but can't make it worked.
For the sensor itself it's almost the same i used, except the type which is 'gpu_lidar' (param value are also little differents, but I did not check yet how important this is).

Note this publish on gz topics, not ROS2, I have to use a bridge to be able to use those data in ROS (but that is expected).

```
<sensor name='gpu_lidar' type='gpu_lidar'>
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <topic>lidar</topic>
```

---

Originally posted by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) with karma: 32 on 2023-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0